# 'All' in "all just ten miles from Manhattan" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Brighton Beach had a marvelous sandy coast looking out on the Atlantic and the adjacent Coney Island amusement park, **all** just ten miles from Manhattan -- everything one could ask for in a delightful seaside resort.

I'm not quite sure how to understand '**all**' in the context.  Does it mean the distance between Coney island and Manhattan ***totally*** just ten miles? Or it refers to all the areas that have been mentioned in the first part of the sentence including Brighton Beach, Coney Island, and etc.?

What's the correct way to understand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“all” here refers to all of Brighton Beach, including the sandy coast.

Edit: it doesn’t include Coney Island, just that one can see the island from that coast.

Comment: Does "the adjacent Coney Island amusement park" belong to Brighton Beach?

Comment: Can we also take 'all' as the the total distance between Brighton Beach and Manhattan?